# Can not do apt-get update, says Could not resolve 'wcdh-dc-wg01'

Tags: 14.04, apt

I did a fresh install of 14.04 from a CD I made on a HP DL380. After the installation I rebooted and did the following with the results below.

What am I missing? and where is that `wcdh-dc-wg01` coming from?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'wcdh-dc-wg01'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'wcdh-dc-wg01'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'wcdh-dc-wg01'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'wcdh-dc-wg01'
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection? Including proper name resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You have Internet connection problem.

Make sure you have an Internet connection (wire, wireless)

It seems your DNS server config can't resolve `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com`.

Try this `$ sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolve.conf`
This solution only works temporarily, after you reboot, it's gone.

I propose 2 solutions for you :

- You can change your DNS resolver/server permanently **per Internet network** by using Network Manager to setup your DNS server for **that network** . For example : you have an wireless network named "Lily", in Network Manager you can statically set your DNS server( at your top right of your screen bar)
- You can change your DNS resolver/server permanently **for every Internet network** by doing this in Ubuntu : `$ sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`

@RE Donald French 2nd comment : There is nothing is returned to apt-get. apt-get requests a (HTTP) connection to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/, and before doing that it needs to ask DNS server first. Since your server is not allowed to connect to Internet -> your DNS request can't be done -> apt-get cannot connect to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/

`Could not resolve 'wcdh-dc-wg01'` indicates that DNS request can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get cannot communicate with that host

open synaptic package mgr -> settings -> repositories -> other software - then search for and remove that `wcdh-dc-wg01` repository

then run `sudo apt-get update` again

Cheers!

Comment: on a side note - what happens when you open web browser and go to `http://security.ubuntu.com`  and  `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com`  The other thing that could be is there could be something going on with your network settings - when i go to these pages I am able to get to index of files ftp blank page

Comment: Neither of those is the problem. That 'url' is not in anything plus I can ping http://us.archive.ubuntu.com. This is a server with no graphic turned on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the server was being blocked by some security at the facility.  The real problem is apt-get is just reading lines from what it gets back from the request if the status is OK.  I am not positive it is OK though. The security at the facility was returning a screen saying that the server was not allowed to access the internet. This was determined by doing a curl on http://us.archive.ubuntu.com and seeing the html for the notice.

apt-get just accepting what is returned as valid with no checks seems like a bug to me. I would have thought it would do a simple sanity check that the url it was going to was at least a real url. wcdh-dc-wg01 is not a valid url in the least bit.

Comment: `apt-get` didn't accept the returned contents as valid. Notice the first part of each line (except the error messages) starts with `Err`, which indicates that there was some error in reading the repository.